# Is there any way for not to generate migration files in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-migration

I am using graph database using rails. I don't want to generate migration while generating models. I know there is a options like `rails g model user --skip-migration`.
But I am searching for permanent solutions what I do not need to specify `--skip-migration` every time while generating model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. You can customize default rails generators (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#customizing-your-workflow). It's actually quite easy. Just add following snippet into your `config/application.rb`:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.orm :active_record, migration: false      
end
```

This tells Rails to use ActiveRecord as an ORM but to skip generation of migrations.

Comment: From my head :). In Ruby and Rails, many things are really natural. If you take a look at the RoR docs you can basically just guest the right options (Although I admit that my first try was `migrations: false`. If this wouldn't work, you can always just browse the code and see what arguments are accepted by the method - beauty of open source ;)

Comment: @MarekTakac I understood. I asked you indirectly to give that source link, where you found. As you already browsed, why should I? :-)